# Copy a part of the file with Java

Tags: java, file, copy

I have a data file that has a header, say 0x270 bytes. Beyond that header, there is a zip file. How can I skip the header part and copy the content of the zip file in a new file?

I am considering trying this, but I am unsure if it will work because I don't have the file to test yet. Is this the right way? Or is there a better way to do it?

```
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("sourcefile");
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
        dis.skipBytes(0x270 );
        File tmpFile = new File("destfile.zip");
        tmpFile.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile, false);
        int read;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[0x10];
        while ((read = dis.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            fos.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        fis.close();
        fos.close();
```

Comment: Thanks, @StephenC. The buffer is actual code is much bigger.

Comment: I think then I can do it with only FileInputStream.

Comment: Well ... my answer is about the code that you showed us.  As far as we are concerned, **that** is the actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks correct. There are other ways to do this, but nothing that is unequivocally better. (Especially since you did not give us a clear quantifiable "goodness" measure.)

There are however a couple of things to note:

1. You are copying the file using a buffer that is way too small. I'd use a 64K byte buffer, not a 16 byte buffer. If you read / write using a tiny buffer you spend more time on system call overheads.   With a buffer this small the overheads are likely to be significant, especially as the input file gets larger.
2. Since the `FileInputStream` class has `skip(long)` method, the `DataInputStream` class is not strictly necessary here.

---

Also:

> "I am considering trying this, but I am unsure if it will work because I don't have the file to test yet."

Surely you can make a file ... for test purposes.  For example, on Linux you can create a stream containing `0x270` zero bytes and append a normal ZIP file to it.  It can probably done in one line using `dd` and `cat` ...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the code may work, but is there a better way to do it? Yes. If you have more recent JDK make use of all available API and try with resources to shorten it to:

```
try(var fis = Files.newInputStream(Path.of("source"));
    var fos = Files.newOutputStream(Path.of("dest"))) {
    fis.skip(numberToSkip);
    fis.transferTo(fos);
}
```

Suitable for JDK11+, or JDK9+ if you switch `Path.of` to `Paths.get`. The `transferTo` call saves writing repetitive use of code like this:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[xyz];
while ((read = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
    fos.write(bytes, 0, read);
}
```